# Disable close Button in IE with javascript

Tags: javascript

Can I disable close button in IE using javascript?
maybe like "Resizeable =no ".
But i dont want to use "fullscreen = yes".
How ?

Thx

Comment: Why? It sounds like you are trying to do something that would harm the user, which isn't a good idea.

Comment: It will help if you explain why you want to do this.

Answer (score 13):

This is impossible in modern browsers.  Browser makers want to provide a user-friendly and relatively predictable experience, which includes not making features that would be useful primarily to makers of spyware or heavily obnoxious, impossible-to-close-without-clicking ads.

Comment: +1 Agreed, trying to hide the close button is bad news to say the least.

Answer (score 3):

The best you can do is to capture the user leaving the page and popup a dialog asking them if they're sure they want to. You cannot cancel the event.

Example (works in IE):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(evt)
        {
            if (unsavedData)
            {
                var message = 'Leaving the page will result in the loss of unsaved data.';
                if (typeof evt == 'undefined')
                {
                    evt = window.event;
                }
                if (evt)
                {
                    evt.returnValue = message;
                }
                return message;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

For security reason, you cannot do that by just using javascript.

Answer (score 2):

If this is for an intranet site or a kiosk, you can use HTML Applications.  HTML Applications are just HTML files that can be made to look and feel like regular Windows applications.

If, for example, you want a full screen Kiosk application just install a proper HTA file on the computer at runs on start up with the following configuration in the head section:

```
<HTA:APPLICATION ID="MyApp" 
    APPLICATIONNAME="Kiosk" 
    BORDER="none"
    CAPTION="no"
    ICON="/graphics/creature.ico"
    SHOWINTASKBAR="no"
    SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
    SYSMENU="no"
    WINDOWSTATE="maximize">
```

The Border="none" part makes a window that doesn't have a close button.

Remember though, this wont work on a regular web page because disabling the close button is a dangerous thing for an untrusted web page to do.  By using an HTA you tell Windows that you can trust this page.

The HTA reference is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536473%28VS.85%29.aspx

And a tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that this is IE only.

Comment: HTAs don't run in IE, so it's not IE only.  It's Windows-only.

Comment: OK. I'm no expert on the subject. I recognised the file extension and dimly remembered it as having something to do with behaviours in IE. And I'd be extremely surprised if these HTAs are not using IE.

Comment: The program that hosts the HTAs uses the IE rendering engine, but with most restrictions turned off.  Regular IE will ignore any HTML files with an <hta:application> tag on the internet, or your local hard drive.  They have to have an .hta extension so that a different program loads them.